# .get() in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I asked a question with the above title a bit ago titled "gettting .get() in jquery to work" and I had made a silly mistake in the code which everyone jumped on. I fixed that but the .get() doesn't seem to be working. Its supposed to print the name John and 2pm on the bottom of the body and it doesn't. My path names are correct. Can someone help?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Site</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id").click(function(){  
            $('#hello').css('background-color', 'blue');
            $.get("test.php",
                function(data){
                    $('body').append( "Name: " + data.name )    //John
                    .append( "Time: " + data.time );            //2pm
                    $('body').css('background-color',     'red');   
                }, "json");
        });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<span id="hello">Hello World!</span>
<input type="button" id="id" value="Click Here"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

heres the php

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm")); 
?>
```

Comment: What do you see in FireBug Console? Is an AJAX request being made? How does it look like? What does the server respond?

Answer (score 1):

you may have better luck using the jQuery `.getJSON()` function, or parsing the data as JSON before using it like you are currently.

[jQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 1):

What version of jQuery are you using? I can reproduce your issue if I go all the way back to 1.3.2. Starting from 1.4, things seem to work as expected. You can see this if you `console.log` your `data` variable. With 1.3.2, you'll see a string as the output, with 1.4+, you'll see an object.

---

As GSto suggests, using [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) will work, even with version 1.3.2.

Comment: If you haven't used the JavaScript `console` object you're missing something :) It's available natively in [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html) and Chrome and with [Firebug in Firefox](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API). If you add `console.log(data)` in your callback method, you'll be able to see what `data` is. In case of JS objects, the console will display them differently while strings will appear as literals.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling it to expect json.  Are you sending json? Try adding

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

to the top of your PHP file.

Comment: It should still work without the header type, in fact, I never include this in my PHP scripts and jQuery still works to parse JSON.

Comment: Try removing the "json" argument so it defaults to "intelligent guess" and attempts to parse what you have by what it thinks it is.